# Frame Showing Problem

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have made one project which is showing the inventory of the stock of one store.
In that inventory the software should store data of the products with their images.
There is one problem...
Bcz of the lots of stock, the screen on which is image is loading taking a lot of time.
So, i thought i should give the frame in which there will be on label which will show the "Loading Software".
But now when i am setting visible = true for that frame, but bcz of that images screen class loading problem my frame is not showing correctly. I have put [screen shot](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4056/4634773646_2375e0b4c9.jpg), now my code.

```
JFrame f;
    try{
            f = new JFrame("This is a test");
            f.setSize(300, 300);
            Container content = f.getContentPane();
            content.setBackground(Color.white);
            content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            JLabel jl = new JLabel();
            jl.setText("Loading Please Wait....");
            content.add(jl);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        initComponents();
        try {
            addInverntory = new AddInventoryScreen(); 
            showstock = new showStock(); // this class will take big time.
            mf = new mainForm();
            f.setVisible(false);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How Can show some message that, other class is loading or "Loading Software" kind of thing in this situation.

Just For the know....this class is not screen on which the image will load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's hard to answer this because it's not clear what the effects (Swing-wise) are of the calls to `new AddInventoryScreen();` and `new showStock();`. You should only touch the UI that the user sees right at the end (when all the processing is done).
2. You should really spin off methods that will take a long time into their own Thread (see [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). There are alternatives for Java 5.0). That way, the UI won't be blocked while it's processing.
3. Maybe what you want is a [Splash Screen](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `validate();` and `pack();` methods before calling `f.setVisible(true);`

Your code can be

```
validate();
pack();
f.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one big problem in your code (maybe not the only one however) is the fact that you should use a **different thread** for long operations.

GUI operations (creating swing components, adding them to panels, changing labels...) are to be performed exclusively in the "[EDT](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)" and must be short (typically, less than 100ms or even 50ms).

Long operations can be easily done by another thread if you use the [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) API (part of JDK 1.6).